# Place a div over an activeX object

Tags: html, activex

I have a div box that needs to pop up over an ActiveX object, but it seems that an ActiveX object has an infinitely high z-index, even if when I set that index to be low.  My div box continues to show up under the ActiveX object.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to place a transparent iframe over the object you want to cover up.

found [this](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html) example for you

Comment: This was part of the answer (making it transparent did not work for me), but I did end up using jQuery to show/hide an iframe with the exact size and position of the div box, as the div box was shown or hidden.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Was presented with the same proble a while back and it took me far too long to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

An advantage of Windowless ActiveX controls is that [they participate in overlapping 2-D layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751970(VS.85).aspx#OC96_and_Windowless_)

Though modifying the control to make it windowless may not be practical.

**Edit:**

I've found [a sample that demonstrate this using the *flash player* ActiveX control](http://www.communitymx.com/content/source/E5141/wmodenone.htm). Flash can be used in both windowed and windowless modes. That sample makes it easy to switch between these and see how an overlapping div appears in each mode.

Windowless controls are implemented in a way that don't require them to have their own window. That means no WindowProc and no dedicated drawing surface.

Instead you receive messages by implementing IOleInPlaceObjectWindowless and can get the GDI drawing context through IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless.

Comment: That looks great!  Although after reading it, I am still not sure how to implement a Windowless ActiveX control.