# Place a semi-transparent div over ActiveX object without iFrame, without Popup

Tags: javascript, html, activex, opacity

I would like to put semi-transparent divs over an ActiveX object which is streaming a video.
I'd like the semi-transparency to allow me to (partially) see the video behind the div.

I have see there are ways to [Place a div over an activeX object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010699/place-a-div-over-an-activex-object) but this involves iFrames, or popups. Not what we're looking for.

We have no control over the ActiveX stream, so we cannot change anything server-side: if we did, we'd just avoid ActiveX.

Comment: iframe ? huh ? Can't you just use "z-index" CSS property ?

Comment: no: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790717/the-good-old-overlapping-menu-how-to-z-index-an-activex

Comment: ah, nice IE ! You right they talk about iframe there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010699/place-a-div-over-an-activex-object

Comment: is the activeX object in an iframe?

Comment: It's not in an iframe, would that help me out?